# Import Variables from Text File in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've got a couple of Powershell scripts that automate DLL transferal and I'd like to import the variables from one text file into the various scripts. My example:

```
Variables.txt
$foo = "blarg"
$bar = "other blarg"
```

And then I'd like to do something like this:

```
Script.ps1
Imports Variables.txt
echo "$foo $bar"
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This can be accomplished by **Dot Sourcing**.

Create a .ps1 file, declare your variables in it, then dot source the file. This will bring any variables declared in the file into the global scope.

Example:

Contents of Variables.ps1:

```
$foo = "blarg"
$bar = "other blarg"
```

Dot source it:

```
. ./Variables.ps1
Write-Host "$foo $bar"
```

Comment: Is there a workaround to use the path for the file that's in a variable? "I'm getting . The term ./$filepath is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program" Error